# Using AppleScript, is it possible to check for unread emails?

Tags: applescript

I just found out about AppleScript, and I'm in the process of learning. I'd like to create something that'll check my email to see if I have a new email. If yes, I want it to return a value (i.e. "Mail"). If not, then I want it to return a different value (i.e. "No Mail"). My idea is to use the Mail application to achieve this.

Looking at the Dictionary for the Mail application (http://www.mugginsoft.com/html/kosmictask/ASDictionaryDocs/Apple/Mail/OS-X-10.7/Mail-5.2/html/), this doesn't look possible since it doesn't seem like you can check for unread mails in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. I used to use it with Geektool to [show a list of *read* messages](http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/apple-mail-desktop-geektool/) that I hadn’t dealt with yet.

In your case, it’s even easier, since you don’t want to keep a list of unread messages, but simply exit as soon as any are discovered.

The flag you’re looking for is “read status”.

```
tell application "Mail"
    if exists (messages of inbox whose read status is false) then
        "Mail"
    else
        "No Mail"
    end if
end tell
```

Note that you do have to be looking in a particular mailbox; in this case, I’m looking at `inbox`. If you are presorting messages to other mailboxes using rules, I’m not aware of any way of doing this using AppleScript without checking each mailbox separately. (Though it might be possible using sqlite directly on Mail’s database file.)

This might also work if you need to look for unread mail in other mailboxes:

```
tell application "Mail"
    if exists (messages of inbox whose read status is false) then
        return "Mail"
    else
        repeat with box in mailboxes
            tell box
                if exists (messages whose read status is false) then
                    return "Mail"
                end if
            end tell
        end repeat
    end if
    return "No Mail"
end tell
```

However, my anecdotal experience is that if you have a complicated setup, running scripts like this (and including this one) will tend to get Mail’s smart (and dumb) mailboxes out of sync with the `read status` of the messages within them.